# Feeding Get-ChildItem path info from an array - Illegal characters

Tags: powershell

I need to iterate over an array of folder names, passing them into `GCI` so I can run operations on their contents. No matter what I do, it keeps giving me this error:

```
gci : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Scripts\Arvest_submission_monitoring.ps1:86 char:5
+     gci -path "D:\subftp\$_" -recurse {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\SUBFTP\folder1:String [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
    DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I've created an array:

```
$folders = "folder1","folder2","folder3"
```

And then iterate over it:

```
$folders | % {
  gci -Path "D:\subftp\$_" -Recurse {
    #do stuff here
  }
}
```

I've tried many various options such as a regex replace to remove any possible illegal characters (although a `$folder.Count` shows me there are no invisible characters), I've tried turning `$folders` into a C# ArrayList but it's still a no go. I've even played around with the path variable itself concatenating it into a single string before use.

The weird thing is if I try and execute it from the command line it works fine. What gives? I'm running v5.

Comment: Have you tried `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`?

Comment: Please show the *actual* paths.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid identifying information, but they all are in this format:
"D:\SUBFTP\58-BANK"
And wouldn't -LiteralPath ignore the variable I'm trying to pass?

Comment: I attempted to use `-LiteralPath` and received the same error

Comment: The variable inside the double-quotes will get expanded _before_ the value is bound to the parameter

Comment: `$folder.Count` is not going to show you anything useful - do `$_.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars())` and observe if it returns any value _other_ than `-1`. ie. `"not?a?valid*filename".IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars())` will return 3 because of the `?` at index 3

Comment: It seems to find fault with the colon and backwards slashes. This makes no sense, I can't execute the command without them.

Comment: We cannot help you when you're withholding relevant information, so would you *please* show the actual paths you're working with? You may redact sensitive information like names, but leave special characters (everything except letters and digits) untouched.

Comment: These are the folder names with bank name changed to BANK:
"D:\SUBFTP\58-BANK","D:\SUBFTP\56-BANK_Adv","D:\SUBFTP\89-BANK"

Comment: Are those the values in `$folders`?

Comment: Yes, those are the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by the curly brace right at the end of your command `gci -Path "D:\subftp\$_" -Recurse {`.

Probably you wanted to do this:

```
$folders | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\subftp\$_" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    #do stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this was the issue, bit of an oversight on my part. Still, the error it was throwing was pretty misleading.